# What is the correct formula for calculating the number of subnets or hosts you can create with a given number of bits represented by x?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I'm pretty sure it is 2x-2 but want to make sure I am correct. Anyone have a say and why?

x2 + 2

2x + 2

2x – 2

x2 – 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of hosts is basically the number of combinations you can make with the number of bits.
In [TCP/IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) the lowest and highest IP of the subnet are reserved as subnet address and broadcast address respectively.

Normally subnets are noted as `192.168.420.0/24` but `x` as you describe it is the remainder of bits when you subtract `x` from the total number of bits available in TCP/IPv4 (spoiler: it's 32).

The formula is `2^x`, explained:

- 2 - the number of possibilities for each bit, `0` or `1`
- ^ - raise to the power of:
- x - the number of bits that is given

I say it's time for some good old manual subnetting.

#### 24 bit example :

i have 24 bits to use.
number of IP's (2^24) = 16777216
range = x.0.0.0 - x.255.255.255

if you create one big subnet it could have 16777214 hosts in it.
network address = x.0.0.0
broadcast address = x.255.255.255
effective ip range = x.0.0.1 - x.255.255.254 (16777214)
subnet masker = 255.0.0.0

#### 16 bit example :

i have 16 bits to use.
number of IP's (2^16) = 65536
range = x.x.0.0 - x.x.255.255

if you create one big subnet it could have 65534 hosts in it.
network address = x.x.0.0
broadcast address = x.x.255.255
effective ip range = x.x.0.1 - x.x.255.254 (65534)
subnet masker = 255.0.0.0

## TL;DR :

**Yes, it is `2^x-2`**

Comment: How did you get (2^24) = 16777216?

Comment: @OmarMiguelSanane I'm in chrome and i used the built in calculator, i pressed F6 and entered `2^24` and below appeared `16777216`. Note that you still need to subtract 2 from `16777216` to obtain the number of hosts.

Comment: The /24 bits represents? The

Comment: @OmarMiguelSanane the /24 in the subnet was used as an example, if you have a /24 subnet you have 8 bits left to make IP's of.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want 2<sup>x</sup> - 2 because in most cases you want to keep the lowest number as a network address and the highest on for broadcast.

You might want to read this post on our sister site:
https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work